# PrimeNG TurboTable with custom width does not work properly

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng, primeng-turbotable

I am trying to use a PrimeNG [turbotable](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table) with custom size (500px) and I expected the columns width to be set automatically however it does not work. I get a horizontal scrollbar and the total width seems to be fixed at 767 pixels. If I try to set the column width manually it gets ignored. If i don't set the table width and I try to put it inside a DIV that is 500px wide I still get the same result (horizontal scrollbar).

Below is the (very simple) code:

```
        <p-table #dt [value]="statusChangesData" [paginator]="true" [alwaysShowPaginator]="false" [rows]="2" [style]="{'width':'500px'}">
            <ng-template pTemplate="caption" >
                <div class="tableCaption">
                    <span translate>Status changes</span>
                </div>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="emptymessage">
                <tr>
                    <td [attr.colspan]="3">
                        <span translate>There are no data into the table</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                <tr>
                    <th style="width:200px" [pSortableColumn]="'date'"><span translate>Date</span><p-sortIcon [field]="'date'"></p-sortIcon></th>
                    <th style="width:200px" [pSortableColumn]="'status'"><span translate>Status</span><p-sortIcon [field]="'status'"></p-sortIcon></th>
                    <th style="width:100px" [pSortableColumn]="'userId'"><span translate>User ID</span><p-sortIcon [field]="'userId'"></p-sortIcon></th>
                </tr>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-col>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{col.date}}</td>
                    <td>{{col.status}}</td>
                    <td>{{col.userId}}</td>
                </tr>
            </ng-template>
        </p-table>
```

and this is what it looks like:

[Turbo Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7o97.png)

As you can see both the header and the paginator respect the width I set (500px) but the body of the table does **not.**

I have tried every suggestion I can find in stack overflow including setting
the style like this:  `[style]="{'width':'200px'}` or using `[autoLayout]="true"` but nothing seems to work. I am using primeNG 7.0.0.

PS. I don't really care to set each column width manually. I just don't want the horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: Did you try to put all the table inside a div with `position : relative; width : 50%;` and then set the width of the table to 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied your code from above and pasted it in a new [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-turbotable-example) project to test it. I even specified the 7.0.0 version of PrimeNG specifically, to make sure there are not any issues with different versions. (I have found that to be the case when I have used PrimeNG.) I also made up some data to show.

I am not seeing the issues you are talking about. Here is what my resulting grid looks like (ignore the fact that Stackblitz is not finding the `primeicons`.)

[image]

It is staying perfectly 500px wide and all columns are obeying the fixed widths you specified in the header row (`<th>` tags.) When I removed the fixed widths you provided in your `<th>` tags, all of the columns are auto-adjusting and fitting within the 500px table.

I have this table in its own component and it is not wrapped in a `<div>` or any other tags. You can check it out on the Stackblitz link I provided above.

I wonder if there is something about the rest of the page this is contained in that is causing the problem?

Comment: You are right, the problem wasn't the primeNG table, someone had defined a min-width for the `.ui-table` in one of the parent css files. Thank you for helping me understand the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone has a similar problem try setting the min-width of the table to 0:

```
::ng-deep .ui-table .ui-table-wrapper table {
    min-width: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Also if someone wants to appear a horizontal scrollbar automated under a specific width is setting the min-width to specific value of px